# Wordpress plugin loads in draft but not when published

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to debug an issue for our product team. Our landing page is Wordpress, and all plugins are working when a new page is saved as a draft, yet when said page is Published, only a few of the plugins are loaded. This is confirmed by a) the short code not working, and more importantly, b) the plugins aren't loaded when viewing the Developer tools.

I appreciate all helps or leads. I'm a full-stack node developer at my work and attempting to help out with this Wordpress issue.
Thanks.